# retrieving the values from responseCookieJar

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

Here is how I am sending a get request:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Network.HTTP.Types

request <- parseUrl $ "someUrl"
res <- withManager $ httpLbs request
putStrLn $ show $ responseCookieJar res
```

Instead of printing `responseCookieJar` I want to get a value from it. This http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#t:CookieJar implies that it's not possible. So I figure I have to parse (by regexp) it as a string. But there must a standard way like getting a value by its key.

Isn't there?

Comment: I've rolled back the update as it's a completely different question and the answer doesn't really fit with the answer to the existing question. (It's a pretty basic problem with precedence, so just try putting in more brackets before actually asking the question)

Comment: Please put your new question in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't keep moving the goalposts for people who answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`destroyCookieJar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3adestroyCookieJar) to break it into the individual [`Cookie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#t%3aCookie)s, and then search that list.

Comment: thanks, but I still can't achieve what I wanted, could take a look?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`destroyCookieJar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3adestroyCookieJar) to turn it into a list of [`Cookie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#t%3aCookie)s, which you can then inspect via various field accessors.

The two most useful for keys are probably [`cookie_name`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3acookie_name) and [`cookie_path`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3acookie_path). So you might do something like

```
filter (\c -> cookie_name c == pack "foo") . destroyCookieJar
```

(using [`pack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v%3apack) from `Data.Bytestring.Char8`)

Or if there are a lot of cookies and you want to do multiple queries, you may want to build something like a `Map` from name to cookie first.

Comment: Haha, we had two nearly identical answers within seconds of each other. +1

Comment: Your update is a separate problem, so it should be a separate question.

Comment: I believe you'll need to `ByteString.pack "foo"` or enable `OverloadedStrings` to do the `== "foo"` comparison.

Comment: (Why did this get downvoted? and, why was *my* answer accepted (this one is better)?)

Comment: @dbaupp because I desire so.